# energy manager for ubuntu laptop lenovo Y700

Tags: lenovo

I have my lenovo Y700 with Ubuntu-Gnome 16.04.
I usually work with all plugged into AC day, Windows Lenovo provides a power manager that in these cases the battery up to 50% so that it does not break in the short term and only depends on the AC and battery charge it is backup.
Someone knows an alternative for Ubuntu and derivatives?
PS: TLP only manages profiles on AC or battery, does not prevent the battery on charge and stressed out when this 100% with AC present.